# csv to xsl java , there is a column with some currency ( like $400 )

Tags: java, excel, apache, csv, apache-poi

I want to convert csv to xsl using Java. Everything is working fine, but there is a column with some currency ( like $400 ) in the CSV file. 
When these currency values are written to the XLS file, it shows green flags and we have to click and change its data type in Excel from string to number to get rid of the green flags.

Now to do so what is thought is to check that in a Cell if starting char is '$' then i will setCelltype to number but what to implement it in code ?

Please help new to excel and java too :P

```
//all imports are proper
public class Convert_CSV_XLS {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        /* Step -1 : Read input CSV file in Java */
        String inputCSVFile = "csv_2_xls.csv";
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(inputCSVFile));
        /* Variables to loop through the CSV File */
        String [] nextLine; /* for every line in the file */            
        int lnNum = 0; /* line number */
        /* Step -2 : Define POI Spreadsheet objects */          
        HSSFWorkbook new_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); //create a blank workbook object
        HSSFSheet sheet = new_workbook.createSheet("CSV2XLS");  //create a worksheet with caption score_details
        /* Step -3: Define logical Map to consume CSV file data into  excel */
        Map<String, Object[]> excel_data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>(); //create a map and define data
        /* Step -4: Populate data into logical Map */
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            lnNum++;                        
            excel_data.put(Integer.toString(lnNum), new Object[] {nextLine[0],nextLine[1]});                      
        }
        /* Step -5: Create Excel Data from the map using POI */
        Set<String> keyset = excel_data.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) { //loop through the data and add them to the cell
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object [] objArr = excel_data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);

                // Now here i want to check if first char of the value in cell is '$' or not.
                if(obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
                else
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
             }
        }
        /* Write XLS converted CSV file to the output file */
        FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("CSV2XLS.xls")); //create XLS file
        new_workbook.write(output_file);//write converted XLS file to output stream
        output_file.close(); //close the file
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check to see if a `String` starts with `$` or not pretty easily.  For setting cell types, it should look like this if you want `Numeric`:

```
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

Comment: please man i want code to check first char '$' of a cell, help me out here
what should i do ? Array arr[] = getCellValue.tostring; 
arr[0] == '$'  ??

Comment: This isn't a code writing service.  I'm helping you with the excel code because that's not "common" knowledge.  Checking for a character in a String in any programming language is pretty basic considering what you're trying to do.  A cursory google search would give you the code.  Show some effort.

Comment: cell.getCellValue would return the value in String ?  then i would do this 
Array arr[] = getCellValue.tostring; 
arr[0] == '$' ??

Comment: Why would `toString` return an array?  And why would you be getting the value from the cell when you had to have the value that you wrote to the cell to begin with?

Comment: I'd suggest reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/) as it will teach you the basics of Java programming.

Comment: ok thanks , i think i can get it working , i should search in the Map itself. but my real question was that can we edit the cell values ? like normal editing (making first char CAPS and all )

Comment: Don't edit the values in the cells if you're writing to the cells to begin with (unless you have to, i.e. setting formatting as in this question).  Edit the values however you have to, then write them to the cells.  Making a `String` all caps is a function built into `String`.

Comment: No not all caps like the 3rd char as caps ? can i make the cell toArray ? and perform some methods ?

Comment: There is no reason you would ever do this on the cell.  Hermant, please go read the basics of Java before you ask how to do something that falls into that category.

Comment: Hey I have tried to do the task but I am not able to format my cell in which "£100" like values are there . In excel I am getting same green flags on these cells
 cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(str));
          CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
          cellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("£#,##0;[Red]-£#,##0"));
          cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

Comment: Well did you follow what I wrote?  I don't see anything in that code setting the cell type.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Used DataFormatter - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html

cells cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(str)); 
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("£#,‌​##0;[Red]-£#,##0")); 
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);